# Structural mechanics

Tags: structural-engineering, applied-mechanics

Ques: I have a question regarding solid mechanics and plate theory,is 2 layer plate means laminated plate or simply refers to as a plate?

Comment: The assumption is a perfect connection between the two plates so they behave as one ie no slip.

Comment: Thankyou for your feedback. you mean it acts as one . But if we have 2 layers plate where the force is applied on the upper layer and deformation on the lower plate, then which category of plate theory this is in?

Comment: I am sorry to inform you that the 2 layer plate are having each layer of different material.

Comment: The assumption still stands... in theory... unless you are working a bi-metallic strip.

Answer (score 1):

A 2-layered plate of different materials would be best handled by means of laminated plate theory.  This is due to the strange side affects of bending-stretching coupling - where bending the material can cause it to pull, and vice-versa.  This is because the centroid is not in the geometric center, and as a result pulling on the two materials will cause vastly different strains that will result in bending-like behavior (as can be seen with a bimetalic strip).